# Regex to extract certifcate component containing comma from a String in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex that can parse the following String value:

```
CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K,OU=(c) 2012 Entrust\, Inc. - for authorized use 
only,OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms,O=Entrust\, Inc.,C=US
```

The following regex works fine for attributes without a comma in the name:

```
C=(.*?)(?:,|$)
```

This will successfully extract the value US from this String. The problem begins with the OU values.

Does anybody have an idea on how to retrieve this value that contains a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\bOU=([^,\\]*(?:\\.[^,\\]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h2ccyr/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `OU=` - a literal `OU=` string
- `([^,\\]*(?:\\.[^,\\]*)*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a `\` and `,` and then zero or more repetitions of any escaped char (other than a newline char, if you need to also match `\n`, prepend your pattern with `(?s)`) and then zero or more chars other than `\` and `,`.

Here is a variation of the same regex with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\bOU=)[^,\\]*(?:\\.[^,\\]*)*
```

Comment: Thnx! This works fine :)